# Unable to start composer 19.x on hyperledgfer fabric 1.1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

While executing steps to install [two org setup using composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) , I am getting error at step 17 i.e. **composer network start** command:

```
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
```

I have already set proxy for npm , and I am able to download node packages as well. I tried using **-o npmrcFile=/tmp/composer/npmConfig** argument as well with npmconfig file having following content :

```
proxy="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/"
https-proxy="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl=false
```

but still no luck. Inside logs am getting

```
  7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/hyperledger-composer
  8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for hyperledger-composer@latest 404  Not Found: hyperledger-composer@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to diagnose and resolve the problem is to create a test container based on the Image that Composer is trying to build, and then test npm inside that container and resolve npmrc config issues.  These commands should help:

`docker run -it --name npmtest --network composer_default --entrypoint "/bin/sh" hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0`

`npm install composer-runtime` ...

`exit`

`docker rm npmtest`

Comment: I started test container and set npm proxy in it and then tried to install node module. It worked fine. Then I merged the container with the ccenv image so that proxy changes stay in image itself. But now when I try to run the install command I am getting error : 2 "/bin/sh: 3: /bin/sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting")")

Comment: The supported way to do this is to specify an npmrc file on the composer network install command e.g.: `composer network install --c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --a tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna -o npmrcFile=/home/user1/config/npmConfig`  this is explained in this doc https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information.html

Comment: i tried that. I have .npmrc file in location /home/.npmrc having proxy config, I gave -o npmrcFile=/home/.npmrc but still its not able to fetch node modules